# How to extract JSON values into string variable to validate for mandatory fields using beanshell assertion

Tags: jmeter, assertion, beanshell

I have written below script in Beanshell assertion to validate some specific value:

import org.json.*; 
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String lastName = responseJson.getString("$data[0]."{last_name}"");

String Message= "";

if (lastName== "lawson")
{
Failure= false;
Message= Message+"Correct value";
FailureMessage= Message;

}
else if (lastName != "lawson") 
{
Failure= true;
Message= Message+"Incorrect value"+lastName;
FailureMessage= Message;
}

Below is the Json:
{
"per_page": 6,
"total": 12,
"data": [
{
"last_name": "Lawson",
"id": 7,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Michael",
"email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in"
},
{
"last_name": "Ferguson",
"id": 8,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Lindsay",
"email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in"
},
{
"last_name": "Funke",
"id": 9,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Tobias",
"email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in"
},
{
"last_name": "Fields",
"id": 10,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Byron",
"email": "byron.fields@reqres.in"
},
{
"last_name": "Edwards",
"id": 11,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg",
"first_name": "George",
"email": "george.edwards@reqres.in"
},
{
"last_name": "Howell",
"id": 12,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Rachel",
"email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in"
}
],
"page": 2,
"total_pages": 2,
"support": {
"text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!",
"url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading"
}
}

But I am getting below error:

Assertion failure message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.json.*; import org.json.JSONArray; import org.json.JSONException; imp . . . '' Encountered "( "$data[0]." { last_name } """ at line 9, column 41.

Can someone please help me what mistake I am making in my script?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code like:

- I don't think [JSONObject.getString()](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString-java.lang.String-) accepts JsonPath, it accepts JSON Object key name only
- You should be comparing strings using [equals() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/)
- Strings are case sensitive, `lawson` and `Lawson` are different entities
- [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

So if you want to continue with code-based approach minimal equivalent code for the [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) would be something like:

```
def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name

if (lastName != 'Lawson') {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect value" + lastName)
}
```

---

Be informed that you can achieve the same using [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was also trying to put validations for multiple fields in the same assertion script and show their results accordingly. How this can be achieved using this same script? Please suggest